# How to stop warnings for functions without DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, meteor-collection2, angular2-meteor

If some function or library does not have **DefinitelyTyped**, I know these two ways to stop warnings.

```
interface Navigator {
  getUserMedia: any
}

declare let RTCIceCandidate: any;
```

But right now, this 3rd-part library [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/) is used like this:

```
let ProductSchema = {};
let Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
Products.attachSchema(ProductSchema);
```

It give me a warning:

> Property 'attachSchema' does not exist on type 'Collection'.

I tried the way below, but it does not work.

```
interface Collection {
  attachSchema: any
}
```

How can I stop this warning? Thanks

**EDIT:**

Eric's adding `any` way solves the problem.

```
let Products:any = new Mongo.Collection('products');
Products.attachSchema(ProductSchema);
```

But now a new trouble comes:

```
let UserSchema = {};
Meteor.users.attachSchema(UserSchema);
```

Since `Meteor.users` is built in, so there is no place to add `any`. How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: The error is completely correct. [These](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are all the methods available for strings in javascript.

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks, I actually want to use string as an example, so now I changed my question more specific

Comment: Have you tried with `let Products: any = new Mongo.Collection('products');`? (note the `any`)

Comment: @EricMartinez wow, that is good trick, ha! thanks!

Comment: That most likely going to fail with the same error if you assign the same/similar value to another variable. I'm not sure this is what you want, but I found this [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/7396) for updating mongodb typings.

Comment: @EricMartinez now I met trouble again, I updated my question. `Meteor.users` is built in Meteor. I have no place to add `any`. Is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: Like this: (<any>Meteor.users).attachSchema(UserSchema);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Amid's help. So the way is:

```
(<any>Meteor.users).attachSchema(UserSchema);
```